# Why is a convex function statisfying $\operatorname{Re}\left(1+\frac{z f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^{\prime}(z)}\right)>0$ is convex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

The condition $\operatorname{Re}\left(1+\frac{z f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^{\prime}(z)}\right)>0$, is used all over our lecture notes to define convex functions. Where does this condition come from? How is related to convexity?

Similar conditions are used to define starlike functions $\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z f^{\prime}(z)}{f^{}(z)}\right)>0$ and close-to-convex functions $\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z f^{\prime}(z)}{g^{}(z)}\right)>0$. Is there a textbook where these are derived or proved?

Comment: I am not a particular stranger to convex analysis but have never seen that condition.

Comment: @copper.hat, it is discussed here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Convex_function_(of_a_complex_variable)#:~:text=and%20are%20complex%20constants%2C%20.&text=The%20argument%20of%20the%20function,for%20the%20function%20%2C%20%2C%20only.

Comment: I guess I still do not understand if $f$ is complex valued, so I will pass.

Comment: Duren Univalent functions has a good introduction to this stuff; one uses geometric conditions on the image to deduce analytic conditions (starlike means that the argument of $f$ increases with the argument on $z$ on each circle and using $\log f =\log |f|+i\arg f$ and the chain rule to express the theta derivative in terms of the $z$ derivative gives the required relation and conversely

Answer (score 0):

Definition. (Carathéodory Functions) Let $p$ be anaytic in the unit disk $\mathbb U$, with $p(0)=1$. For $0 \leq \alpha < 1$, denote by $\mathcal{P}_\alpha$ the class of functions $p$ with Taylor series expansion
$$p(z) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n z^n$$
satisfying
$$\operatorname{Re}p(z) > \alpha \quad (z\in \mathbb U).$$
Functions in $\mathcal{P}_0$, which we denote by $\mathcal{P}$, are referred as functions with positive real part, or Carathéodory functions.

Let $\mathcal{S}^*$ denotes the subclass of starlike functions.

Theorem. Let $f$ be analytic in $\mathbb U$, with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Then $f\in \mathcal{S}^*$ if, and only if, $zf'(z)/f(z) \in \mathcal{P}$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}\label{Equation4.1}
    \operatorname{Re} \left\{ \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} \right\} > 0 \quad (z \in \mathbb U).
\end{equation}

Proof. Suppose first that $f\in \mathcal{S}^*$. We first show that $f$ maps each disk $|z| < \rho < 1$ onto a starlike domain. Thus, we need to show that $g(z) = f(\rho z)$ is starlike in $\mathbb U$, i.e., that for each fixed $t \in [0, 1]$ and each $z \in \mathbb U$, the point $tg(z)$ lies in the range of $g$. Since $f\in \mathcal{S}^*$, an application of the Schwarz's lemma gives $tf(z) = f(w(z))$ for some function $w$ analytic in $\mathbb U$ and satisfying $|w(z)|\leq |z|$. Thus
$$tg(z) = t f(\rho z) = f(w(\rho z)) = f\left( \rho \frac{w(\rho z)}{\rho} \right) = f(\rho w_1(z))  =   g(w_1(z)),$$
where $w_1(z) = w(\rho z)/\rho$ and $|w_z(z)| \leq |z|$.

This proves that $f$ maps each circle $|z|=\rho < 1$ onto a curve $C_\rho$ that bounds a starlike domain. It follows that $\operatorname{arg} f(z)$ increases as $z$ moves around the circle $|z|=\rho$ in the positive direction. In other words,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left\{ \arg f(\rho e^{i\theta}) \right\} \geq 0.$$
We shall obtain an analytic representation of functions in $\mathcal{S}^*$ in terms of $\mathcal{P}$ from above equation. Since $z = \rho e^{i\theta}$
\begin{split}
     \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left\{ \arg f(\rho e^{i\theta}) \right\} & = \operatorname{Im}  \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(\rho e^{i\theta}) \right\} \\
     & =  \operatorname{Im}  \left\{ \frac{izf'(z)}{f(z)} \right\} = \operatorname{Re}  \left\{ \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} \right\}.
\end{split}
Thus $zf'(z)/f(z) \in \mathcal{P}$, by the maximum principle for harmonic functions.

Conversely, suppose $f$ is a normalized analytic function that is $f(0)=0$ and $f'(z) =1$ with $zf'(z)/f(z) \in \mathcal{P}$. Then $f$ has a simple zero at the origin and no zeros elsewhere in $\mathbb U$. Reversing the above argument shows that for each $\rho < 1$,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left\{ \arg f(\rho e^{i\theta}) \right\} > 0, \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi.$$
Thus, as $z$ travels around the circle $|z| = \rho$ in the counter-clockwise direction, the point $f(z)$ moves around a closed curve $C_\rho$ with increasing argument. Since $f$ has only one zero inside $|z| = \rho$, the argument principle tells us that $C_\rho$ surrounds the origin exactly once. Hence, $C_\rho$ cannot intersect itself, and so is a simple closed curve bounding a starlike domain $D_\rho$, which is the interior of $C_\rho$, and $f$ assumes each value in $D_\rho$ exactly
once in the disk $|z| < \rho$. Since this is true for every $\rho < 1$, it follows that $f$ is univalent and starlike in $\mathbb U$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denotes the subclass of convex functions.

Theorem. Let $f$ be analytic in $\mathbb U$, with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Then $f\in \mathcal{C}$ if, and only if, $1+zf''(z)/f'(z) \in \mathcal{P}$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}\label{Equation4.2}
    \operatorname{Re} \left\{1 + \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)} \right\} > 0 \quad (z \in \mathbb U).
\end{equation}

Proof.     Suppose first that $f\in \mathcal{C}$. We claim that $f$ must map each each subdisk $|z|<r<1$ onto a convex domain. To show this, choose points $z_1$ and $z_2$ with $|z_1|\leq |z_2|<r$. Let $w_1=f(z_1)$ and $w_2=f(z_2)$. Let
$$w_0 = tw_1 + (1-t)w_1, \quad 0<t<1.$$
Then since $f$ is a convex mapping, there is a unique point $z_0 \in \mathbb U$ for which $f(z_0)=w_0$. We have to show that $|z_0|<r$. But the function
$$g(z) = tf(z_1 z/z_2) + (1-t)f(z)$$
is analytic in $\mathbb U$, with $g(0)=0$ and $g(z_2)=w_0$. Since $f\in \mathcal{C}$, the function
$$h(z)=f^{-1}(g(z))$$
is well-defined. Since $h(0)=0$ and $|h(z)|\leq 1$, Schwarz's lemma tells us that $|h(z)|\leq |z|$. Thus
$$|z_0| = |h(z_2)|\leq |z_2| < r,$$
which was to be shown. Hence $f$ maps each circle $|z|=r<1$ onto a curve $C_r$ which bounds a convex domain. The convexity implies that the slope of the tangent to $C_r$ is non-decreasing as the curve is traversed in the positive direction. Analytically, this can be expressed as
\begin{split}
0 \leq  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left( \arg \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(r e^{i\theta}) \right\} \right)  
& =  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left( \arg \left\{ ire^{i\theta} f'(r e^{i\theta}) \right\} \right) \\
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \operatorname{Im} \left\{\log\left[ ir e^{i\theta} f'(r e^{i\theta})\right] \right\} \\
& = \operatorname{Im} \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log\left[ ir e^{i\theta} f'(r e^{i\theta})\right] \right\} \\
& = \operatorname{Im} \left\{ \frac{ir e^{i\theta}[if'(re^{i\theta})+ire^{i\theta}f''(re^{i\theta})]}{ire^{i\theta} f'(re^{i\theta})}\right\} \quad (z=re^{i\theta})
\end{split}
which reduces to the condition
$$\operatorname{Re} \left\{ 1 + \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)} \right\} \geq 0, \quad |z|=r. $$
Thus by the maximum principle for harmonic functions we have shown that $\left[1 + zf''(z)/f'(z)\right] \in \mathcal{P}$.

To prove the converse, suppose that $f$ is normalized as before and $\left(1 + zf''(z)/f'(z)\right) \in \mathcal{P}$. From the above, the slope of the tangent to $C_r$ increases monotonically. But as a point makes a complete revolution around $C_r$, the argument of the tangent vector satisfies

\begin{split}
    \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left( \arg \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(re^{i\theta}) \right\} \right) d\theta & = \int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{Re} \left\{ 1+ \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)} \right\} d\theta \\
    & = \operatorname{Re} \left\{ \int_{|z|=r} \left[1+ \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)} \right] \frac{dz}{iz} \right\} = 2 \pi, \quad z = re^{i\theta}.
\end{split}

This shows that for any $C_r$ is a simple closed curve bounding a convex domain. This for arbitrary $r<1$ implies that $f$ is a univalent function, whose range is a convex domain. We also note that $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{S}^*$.